# How can I read html that loads after the rest of the other html?

Tags: java, regex, bufferedreader

Ok, Sorry the question is crap. It's hard to put into a question :P

If you put a word like Thought into dictionary.com or any irregular verb the pronunciation [thawt] loads after the rest of the html.

If you check my code you'll see what i mean. Instead of [thawt] it loads [thingk]..

```
package OEpr;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardOwner;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class OEpr {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField txtWord;
    private JTextField textpron;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */

    private static String wordurl;
    private static String line;
    private int linenum;
    private static int findingfirst = 0;
    private static String pron;
    StringSelection testcopy;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    OEpr window = new OEpr();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public OEpr() {
        initialize();

        setvars();

    }

    public void setvars() {
        OEpr.wordurl = "http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/"
                + txtWord.getText();

    }

    public void geturl(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Set URL

        URL url = new URL(wordurl);
        URLConnection spoof = url.openConnection();
        // Spoof the connection so we look like a web browser
        spoof.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0; H010818)");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                spoof.getInputStream()));
        String uline = "";

        // Loop through every line in the source
        while ((uline = in.readLine()) != null) {

            System.out.println(uline);
            line = uline;

            linecheck();
        }
        // System.out.println(OEpr.line);
    }

    private void linecheck() {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<!-- google_ad_section_start -->");
        Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("\\[.*?]");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(OEpr.line);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            findingfirst++;
            // if(findingfirst==2){

            String noHTML = line.replaceAll("\\<.*?>", "");
            Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(noHTML);
            if (matcher2.find()) {
                pron = noHTML.replaceAll("(^.*(?=\\[))|((?<=\\]).*$)", "");
                // System.out.println(pron);
                textpron.setText(pron);
            }

            // }
            // System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); //prints /{item}/
        } else {
            // System.out.println("Match not found");
        }
    }

    public void setClipboardContents(String aString) {

        testcopy = new StringSelection(pron);

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard()
                .setContents(testcopy, null);

    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(210, 100);
        JButton btnGo = new JButton("Go!");
        btnGo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                // Execute when button is pressed
                try {
                    setvars();
                    OEpr.findingfirst = 0;
                    geturl(null);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        JButton btnCopy = new JButton("Copy!");
        btnCopy.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                // Execute when button is pressed
                try {
                    setClipboardContents(null);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        txtWord = new JTextField();
        txtWord.setText("thought");
        txtWord.setColumns(10);

        textpron = new JTextField();
        textpron.setColumns(10);
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane());
        groupLayout
                .setHorizontalGroup(groupLayout
                        .createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(
                                Alignment.TRAILING,
                                groupLayout
                                        .createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGroup(
                                                groupLayout
                                                        .createParallelGroup(
                                                                Alignment.LEADING)
                                                        .addGroup(
                                                                groupLayout
                                                                        .createSequentialGroup()
                                                                        .addContainerGap(
                                                                                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                                                Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                                        .addComponent(
                                                                                txtWord,
                                                                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                        .addPreferredGap(
                                                                                ComponentPlacement.RELATED))
                                                        .addGroup(
                                                                groupLayout
                                                                        .createSequentialGroup()
                                                                        .addContainerGap()
                                                                        .addComponent(
                                                                                textpron,
                                                                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                        .addPreferredGap(
                                                                                ComponentPlacement.RELATED)))
                                        .addGroup(
                                                groupLayout
                                                        .createParallelGroup(
                                                                Alignment.LEADING)
                                                        .addComponent(btnGo)
                                                        .addComponent(btnCopy))
                                        .addContainerGap()));
        groupLayout
                .setVerticalGroup(groupLayout
                        .createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(
                                groupLayout
                                        .createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addContainerGap()
                                        .addGroup(
                                                groupLayout
                                                        .createParallelGroup(
                                                                Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                        .addComponent(btnGo)
                                                        .addComponent(
                                                                txtWord,
                                                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addPreferredGap(
                                                ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addGroup(
                                                groupLayout
                                                        .createParallelGroup(
                                                                Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                        .addComponent(btnCopy)
                                                        .addComponent(
                                                                textpron,
                                                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addContainerGap(
                                                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Methinks you are asking about [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).

Comment: if i understand what you are saying the page loads and it says a certain thing then it executes the ajax script and changes the text inside. But when you load it you don't have that ajax script running so you can't get it. You will need to know what is the script they run and where they send it (action). once you do that you can then send the same thing to the server and get the response that you are seeking. It will either return Json or html text then you need to replace in the same spot. if this is case and point. Look in script file for something that matches the same id that is replaced